# how can i create custom field with script runner?

Tags: groovy, jira

My epics contain the system field Rank, How can I add this field to the tasks of my epic using the script runner or other tools ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `com.atlassian.greenhopper.api.rank.RankService` class

Try this to make rank of issue1 after issue2:

```
import com.atlassian.greenhopper.api.rank.RankService
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.WithPlugin
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.JiraAgileBean
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

@WithPlugin('com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira')

@JiraAgileBean
RankService rankService

def user = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getUserByKey('userName')
def issue1 = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueByCurrentKey("KEY")
def issue2 = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueByCurrentKey("KEY")
def rank = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(rankFieldId)

rankService.rankAfter(user, rankFieldId, issue1, issue2)
```